# Pass sprite to function cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am making pong in cocos2dx and would like to make a function that would take a sprite as an input together with the direction of movement. VC2012 spits out an error on compilation

Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Sprite' (..\Classes\AppDelegate.cpp)
Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Sprite' (..\Classes\HelloWorldScene.cpp)
Error   4   error C2660: 'HelloWorld::movePaddle' : function does not take 2 arguments
Error   5   error C2511: 'void HelloWorld::movePaddle(cocos2d::Sprite *,int)' : overloaded member function not found in 'HelloWorld'

Here is the function:

```
void HelloWorld::movePaddle(Sprite *paddle, int direction) {
    paddle->runAction(MoveBy::create(1,Point(0,15*direction)));
}
```

Here is the function prototype in the .h file:

```
void HelloWorld::movePaddle(Sprite *paddle, int direction);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I apologise if this question seems stupid, I'm very new.

Comment: Two possible causes: You have not included the header file that defines `cocos2d::Sprite`. Or you forgot `using namespace cocos2d` (which I personally recommend against, I'd rather write `codos2d::Sprite`).

Comment: OMG was about to reply that I found it to be the cocos2d::Sprite. How do I mark as solved question?